# serverless chat client that works across subnets?

Tags: chat, centos-7

I'm looking for a Linux (CentOS 7) based chat application that I can use to simply send chat messages directly to an IP address (on a machine that's running the same client). I want to avoid installing and configuring a chat server if I can.

I've found iptux, and Empathy/Telepathy (People Nearby feature) which do almost exactly what I want to do through the use of Avahi, Bonjour, or XMPP protocols but they only work by discovering machines on the same LAN. I; on the other hand, need to be able to talk to IPs that are not on my local LAN or subnet. This is not a terribly complex network but it does have multiple subnets with a router in between. I should also point out that the router is simply routing between subnets and not performing anything special like NAT or blocking any traffic with an ACL.

Is anyone aware of a tool like iptux, or Empathy that'll allow me to specify the IP address of the distant end machine that I'd like to talk to? I think I've read that netstat and/or netcat can be used similarly to DOS' "Net Send" command but is there anything with a GUI?

Thanks in advance for any responses.